# How to iterate only on part of 2D array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have 2D array

```
var arr = [[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
           [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
           [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
           [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
           [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]];
```

Now we are dividing this into smaller parts like 2x2. How to iterate only on part (block) of this array e.g: items with indexes `arr[2][4]`, `arr[2][5]`, `arr[3][4]`, `arr[3][5]`?

**Edit:**

Seems question is not easy understandable. I want to iterate over blocks.

```
var blocks = 9;
var output = '';
for( var block = 0; block < blocks; block++) { 
  // actual iteration over array
  for(var i = ... ) {
    for(var j = ... ) {
      output += arr[i][j] + ' ';
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
  output = '';
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
0 1 6 7
2 3 8 9
4 5 10 11
12 13 18 19
14 15 20 21
16 17 22 23
24 25 30 31
26 27 32 33
28 29 34 35
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocks, blocks = 9, etc?

Comment: `blocks` is total amount of logic blocks

Comment: Please define a logic block

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest `for` loops.

```
var arr = [[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]];

function loopThrough() {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // this will give you arr[0], arr[1], etc.
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            // this will give you arr[0][0], arr[0][1], etc.
            console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

loopThrough();
```

If you want it to loop over only the last 2, then set `j] = arr[i].length-2`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = [[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]];

function loopThrough() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // this will give you arr[0], arr[1], etc.
        for(var j = arr[i].length-2; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            // this will give you arr[0][0], arr[0][1], etc.
            console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

loopThrough();

</script>
```

Comment: This also needs to offset the inner loop, so it iterates over the last two positions only.

Comment: @AdamKonieska, didn't see that. Have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to access those indexes in order :

```
arr[0][0] arr[0][1] arr[1][0] arr[1][1]
arr[0][2] arr[0][3] arr[1][2] arr[1][3]
[...]
arr[0][y-1] arr[0][y] arr[1][y-1] arr[1][y] // first two lines processed
arr[2][0] arr[2][1] arr[3][0] arr[3][1]     // we continue with the next two lines
[...]
arr[2][y-1] arr[2][y] arr[3][y-1] arr[3][y]
[...]
arr[x-1][0] arr[x-1][1] arr[x][0] arr[x][1]
[...]
arr[x-1][y-1] arr[x-1][y] arr[x][y-1] arr[x][y]
```

As you can see we have two levels of iteration : a first one iterates over the lines, skipping every other one, and a second one iterates over the columns, skipping every other one.

The following code should implement this :

```
for (var x=0; x < arr.length; x+=2) {
  for (var y=0; y < arr[x].length; y+=2) {
    console.log(arr[x][y] + " " + arr[x][y+1] + " " + arr[x+1][y] + " " + arr[x+1][y+1]);
  }
}
```

You will notice that we increment the iterations variables by two each loop, since the inner block consumes two columns and lines at once.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid - implicit setting startX and startY. Array should be logically divided into blocks. Checkout my edit.

Comment: @makbol edited, and here's a JSFiddle showcasing the result : http://jsfiddle.net/LLjeq61t/ ; please tell me if the explanation isn't clear enough, I'll try and update it

Comment: So far your answer is the closest to what I wanted to achieve but loop should iterate over elements within block, not explicitly setting boundaries.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit now.

So I'd expect: 1st iteration within block 1 gets: `arr[0][0]`, 2nd: `arr[0][1]`, 3rd: `arr[1][0]`, 4th: `arr[1][1]`. 1st iteration within block 2 get: `arr[0][2]`, 2nd: `arr[0][3]`, 3rd: `arr[1][2]`, 4th: `arr[1][3]` ... etc.

Comment: @makbol You need to define the boundaries because javascript does not have a logic block construct, so you have to give specify them.  The code that was provided does loop over those items, and in the order you're asking for when you say `arr[0][0]`, 2nd `arr[0][1]` etc.  Thats exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: @markbol you can iterate easily inside a block. A smart way to do so would be to count to 4 and to use modulo and integer division : `for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) { console.log(arr[Math.floor(i/2)][i%2]); }`. The dumb and easy way would be to use two more `for` loops

Comment: @markbol thinking about it you could even implement the whole iteration with just one `for` loop and the good arithmetic operations. Not that it would be a good idea, it would be more cpu-intensive for no good reason.

Comment: @markbol oh and I forgot to add x and y in my previous comment. It should have been `for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) { console.log(arr[x+Math.floor(i/2)][y+i%2]); }`

Answer (score 0):

You would need a loop with an offset inner loop to iterate over the last two positions.  Something like this would work, you can see the results on this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wfysb38/3/

```
var arr = [[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
           [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
           [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
           [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
           [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]];



for(i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i=i+2) {
    for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length - 1; j=j+2) {
        strOut = '';
        strOut = strOut + ', ' +arr[i][j];
        strOut = strOut + ', ' +arr[i][j+1];
        strOut = strOut + ', ' +arr[i+1][j];
        strOut = strOut + ', ' +arr[i+1][j+1];
        strOut = strOut.substring(1,strOut.length)
        console.log(strOut);
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated to code to produce results matching the expected output.  The key is to iterate the loops by 2, and seek the next position in the array by offsetting.  This is not very flexible, and the array this loops over should be structured appropriately.

Comment: In this approach you would iterate over columns 4, 5.

Comment: @makbol that was what you requested before editing the post, iterating on [16,17], [22,23], etc.  Are you trying to accomplish something different now?

Comment: No. Checkout result for fiddle you've pasted. The output is 4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17, 22, 23, 28, 29, 34, 35

Comment: @makbol, you're asking in your question ' How to iterate only on part (block) of this array e.g: items with indexes arr[2][4], arr[2][5], arr[3][4], arr[3][5]?' which is exactly the items being returned.  Your expected output of '0 1 6  7
2 3 8  9
4 5 10 11' does not match what you are asking.  The items you're asking to be iterated do not match your expected output.

Comment: Yes they are. Items: `arr[2][4]`, `arr[2][5]`, `arr[3][4]`, `arr[3][5]` are part of logic _block_ so they will be `16 17 22 23`

Comment: @makbol Thats my point, 16 17 22 23 are not listed in your expected output.

Comment: Well I was thinking that there is not need to write next lines because you can get point from first ones. I will edit output.

Comment: @makbol thanks, I think I see what you're asking now. I've updated the fiddle here to produce the results you're looking for. The key is iterating the loops by 2. jsfiddle.net/0wfysb38/3/

Comment: Your answer is very similar to [one above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33784099/1060408) . See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783951/how-to-iterate-only-on-part-of-2d-array-in-javascript#comment55392232_33784099)

Answer (score 0):

```
function subblock_array(arr, startX, endX, startY, endY) {  
    var subArr = [];
    for (var ii=startX; ii<endX; ii++) {
        subArrY = [];
        for (var jj=startY; jj<endY; jj++) {
            subArrY.push(arr[ii][jj]);
        }
        subArr.push(subArrY);
    }
    return subArr;
}

subblock_array(arr, 2, 4, 4, 6)
```